# CMake 2.8.12 with VS2010 compiler has error when building the CGAL-4.3

Tags: c++, cgal, visual-studio-2010

I am a fresh on CGAL, I met a problem, my CMake2.8.12 (VS2010 c++ express version) seems can not work for the CGAL 4.3. I put the Error.log here

```
Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe cmTryCompileExec3635631916.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18052]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 11/18/2013 9:30:40 AM.

Project "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCXXCompiler.cxx

  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCXXCompiler.cxx



  testCXXCompiler.cxx

ManifestResourceCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe /nologo /fo"cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.exe.embed.manifest.res" cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3635631916_manifest.rc 

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3635631916.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3635631916.lib" /MACHINE:X86 cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.exe.embed.manifest.res

  cmTryCompileExec3635631916.dir\Debug\testCXXCompiler.obj  /machine:X86 /debug 

LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3635631916.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20



Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe cmTryCompileExec3236418378.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18052]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 11/18/2013 9:32:41 AM.

Project "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCXXCompiler.cxx

  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCXXCompiler.cxx



  testCXXCompiler.cxx

ManifestResourceCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe /nologo /fo"cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.exe.embed.manifest.res" cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3236418378_manifest.rc 

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3236418378.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3236418378.lib" /MACHINE:X86 cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.exe.embed.manifest.res

  cmTryCompileExec3236418378.dir\Debug\testCXXCompiler.obj  /machine:X86 /debug 

LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3236418378.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20



Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe cmTryCompileExec787580669.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18052]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 11/18/2013 9:35:54 AM.

Project "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec787580669.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec787580669.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCXXCompiler.cxx

  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCXXCompiler.cxx



  testCXXCompiler.cxx

ManifestResourceCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe /nologo /fo"cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec787580669.exe.embed.manifest.res" cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec787580669_manifest.rc 

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTryCompileExec787580669.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec787580669.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec787580669.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL-4.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec787580669.lib" /MACHINE:X86 cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec787580669.exe.embed.manifest.res

  cmTryCompileExec787580669.dir\Debug\testCXXCompiler.obj  /machine:X86 /debug 

LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec787580669.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec787580669.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec787580669.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\Program Files (x86)\CGAL-4.3\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec787580669.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20
```

I dont know what to do, please help me.  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Try to build the lib in another directory than program files. Also check [this page](http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html)

Comment: i have tried , but not worked

Comment: Did you clean the cache? The error indicates the compiler is not working (that is nothing related to CGAL) and a common mistake is to compile the source in Program Files where sometimes the compile does not have the right to write.

Comment: I run cmake as admin, but still unwork. it keeps on saying :CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/CGAL-4.3/examples/AABB_tree/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Comment: I found the problem, it is .NET Framework 4.5,  VS2010 cannot work with 4.5, I change it to 4.0 version then it works

Answer (score 0):

Your version number indicates you're not running SP1. Update Visual Studio 2010, then the problem should be solved, as it was for me.